# Beamer shadow weight/colour

Tags: beamer, beamerposter

I'd like to increase the weight and colour of a beamer shadow.

The code to create a block with a shadow in Beamer is:

```
\begin{beamercolorbox}[rounded=true,shadow=true]{title} 
  blah
\end{beamercolorbox}%
```

I'm basically after a way to get more shadow.

Thanks.

[image: shadow]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[tcolorbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) is very useful to produce this kind of boxes. It includes a library (`skins`) which among other features introduces command

> ```
> shadow={<xshift>}{<yshift>}{<offset>}{<options>}
> ```
>
> Adds a new shadow to the stack of shadows. This shadow is follows the
>   outline of the `tcolorbox` but is shifted by  and .
>   The  value is a distance value from the frame outline. A
>   positive  value shrinks the shadow and a negative 
>   value enlarges the shadow. The shadow is filled along a TikZ path with
>   the given TikZ .

Next code is adapted (to a more `beamer` style) from an example in tcolorbox's userguide.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{enhanced,colback=red!5!white,
colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,bottomrule=0pt,leftrule=0pt,rightrule=0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=My own shadow,
shadow={2mm}{-1mm}{0mm}{black!50!white}]
This is a tcolorbox.
\end{tcolorbox}
\par\bigskip
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Another shadow,
shadow={-1mm}{-2mm}{0mm}{fill=blue,
opacity=0.5}]
This is a tcolorbox.
\end{tcolorbox}
\par\bigskip
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Double shadow,
shadow={-1.5mm}{-1.5mm}{0mm}{fill=blue,
opacity=0.25},
shadow={1.5mm}{-1.5mm}{0mm}{fill=red,
opacity=0.25}]
This is a tcolorbox.
\end{tcolorbox}
\par\bigskip
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Far shadow,
shadow={5.5mm}{-3.5mm}{2mm}{fill=black,
opacity=0.25}]
This is a tcolorbox.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]